# Vaadin combobox with different properties to display and bind

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

I have two domain classes

```
public class A {
  private String nick;
  private String bId;

  // getters & setters
}

public class B {
  private String id;
  private String name;

  // a lot of other fields
  // getter and setters
}
```

The idea is that `A` does not save a complete `b`, but only its id.

Now I like to create a form in Vaadin (7.6.7) to create a new `A`. There are a limited number of `B` objects available, so I like to have a Combobox, where the user can select a `B`.

As the `id` of `B` is a non-user-friendly field, I like to have a Combobox, that is bound to the property `bId` in the `A` object and presents itself with the property `name` of `B`.

I cannot figure out how this code shall look like.

```
FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
BeanFieldGroup<A> dataBinder = new BeanFieldGroup(A.class);
Field<?> nickField = dataBinder.buildAndBind("nick");
layout.addComponent(nickField);

Combobox bBox = new Combobox("B");
List<B> allBs = ... // get all Bs;
allBs.stream().forEach(bBox::addItem);
dataBinder.bind(bBox, "bId");
// this does not work really
```

I know the problem is that I have bound a combobox with type `B` to a field of the type `String`, but how do I make it, that I can show all `B`s with the name in the Combobox, but when the `commit` is happening, it uses the `id` of `B` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to set the item captions explicitly by using `ComboBox.setItemCaption(..)`:

```
for (final B b : allBs) {
    bBox.setItemCaption(b.getId(), b.getName());
}
```

Then you bind your ComboBox' property to A's bId and the ComboBox' container data source to a list of B Ids you set up yourself.

```
bBox.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(
            String.class, allBIds));
```

or manually set the ComboBox items:

```
for (final B b : allBs) {
    bBox.addItem(b.getId());
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/apm78/demo-combobox) is an example with ComboBoxes that might help you too.

Comment: Alternative approach maybe a `Converter` on the `ComboBox` that gets the ID out of B objects when you fill your B objects in the combo box but I didn't try it so far.